# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using an object oriented chart and setting data according to the scroll position.
I'm using d3.csv() to load data with then(), like this:

```
const chart = new Chart(instatiatechartfunctions);

let dataObj1 = d3.csv('datapath', dataparsefunction);
let dataObj2 = d3.csv('datapath2', dataparsefunction);

let dataArr = [dataObj1,dataObj2];

function init(data){
     chart.setData(data);
    }

let g3 = scrollerfunction().settings()
                           .on('active', function(i){
                                dataArr[i].then(init); //error here
                                });
```

It's quite complicated for me to include the scroller library along with all the code for the chart, so I hope the above is clear enough.
My main issue is that calling `init` in `then()` with no () shows the graph but returns the error in the title. when I use the parentheses (`then(init())`) I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
```

I am using d3.v6
Can anyone help?

Comment: `.on('active', function(i){console.log(i, dataArr.length, dataArr[i]); ....` So debug and find out what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting `.then(init)` without the parenthesis is the equivalent to saying `.then((array) => init(array))`, as in both cases you are giving `.then` a one-argument function to execute on the return of your promise. If the error then shows up in the title, I guess that there's something going on in that part of the code, but not here.